# Tensorflow cross-entropy NaN, and changing learning rate doesn't seem to have an impact

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

TL;DR
Trying to build a bidirectional RNN for sequence tagging using tensorflow.

The goal is to take inputs "I like New York" and produce outputs "O O LOC_START LOC"

The graph compiles and runs, but the loss becomes NaN after 1 or 2 batches. I understand this could be a problem with the learning rate, but changing the learning rate seems to have no impact. Using AdamOptimizer at the moment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

Code:

```
    # The input and output: a sequence of words, embedded, and a sequence of word classifications, one-hot
    self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_sequence_length, n_embedding_dim], name="input_x")
    self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_sequence_length, n_output_classes], name="input_y")

    # New shape: [sequence_length, batch_size (None), embedding_dim]
    inputs = tf.transpose(self.input_x, [1, 0, 2])

    # New shape: [sequence_length * batch_size (None), embedding_dim]
    inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1, n_embedding_dim])

    # Define weights
    w_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_embedding_dim, 2 * n_hidden_states]))
    b_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2 * n_hidden_states]))

    w_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2 * n_hidden_states, n_output_classes]))
    b_out = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_output_classes]))

    # Linear activation for the input; this will make it fit to the hidden size
    inputs = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(inputs, w_hidden, b_hidden)

    # Split up the batches into a Python list
    inputs = tf.split(0, n_sequence_length, inputs)

    # Now we define our cell. It takes one word as input, a vector of embedding_size length
  cell_forward = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_states, forget_bias=0.0)
  cell_backward = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_states, forget_bias=0.0)

  # And we add a Dropout Wrapper as appropriate
  if is_training and prob_keep < 1:
        cell_forward = rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell_forward, output_keep_prob=prob_keep)
        cell_backward = rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell_backward, output_keep_prob=prob_keep)

    # And we make it a few layers deep
    cell_forward_multi = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell_forward] * n_layers)
    cell_backward_multi = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell_backward] * n_layers)

    # returns outputs = a list T of tensors [batch, 2*hidden]
    outputs = rnn.bidirectional_rnn(cell_forward_multi, cell_backward_multi, inputs, dtype=dtypes.float32)

    # [sequence, batch, 2*hidden]
    outputs = tf.pack(outputs)

    # [batch, sequence, 2*hidden]
    outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, [1, 0, 2])

    # [batch * sequence, 2 * hidden]
    outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, 2 * n_hidden_states])

    # [batch * sequence, output_classes]
    self.scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(outputs, w_out, b_out)

    # [batch * sequence, output_classes]
    inputs_y = tf.reshape(self.input_y, [-1, n_output_classes])

    # [batch * sequence]
    self.predictions = tf.argmax(self.scores, 1, name="predictions")

    # Now calculate the cross-entropy
    losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(self.scores, inputs_y)
    self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses, name="loss")

    if not is_training:
        return

    # Training
    self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(self.loss)

    # Evaluate model
    correct_pred = tf.equal(self.predictions, tf.argmax(inputs_y, 1))
    self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32), name="accuracy")
```

Comment: You'll get a `NaN` if you produce 0 score for a label that's present in the data, one workaround is to add a small epsilon to your scores

Comment: Thanks. Are you suggesting I modify this:
self.scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(outputs, w_out, b_out)

To something like this
self.scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(outputs, w_out, b_out) + epilson_matrix

Comment: Running it now after adding tf.constant(0.001, shape=[n_output_classes]) as my epsilon... should only take a minute to break, or not. :-) We'll see.

Comment: Still NaN with the epsilon .

Comment: What you change learning rate to 0?

Comment: Ran it with self.train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0).minimize(self.loss)

Still got NaN on 2nd batch

Comment: OK, so it's not a problem of learning, you are getting NaN in your forward pass or gradients somewhere. `tf.check_numerics` is useful in isolating where `NaN` happens

Comment: Hi, Tom, I had a very similar [task](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11975/word-labeling-with-tensorflow) and I was thinking about using the same approach (bi-derictional LSTM) though never got time to go through with it, mostly due to limited knowledge of TF/ML. I was wondering if you made your code work and whether or not you got good results? Thanks!

Comment: @maga sorry for the extra-long delay. No, I never got it to work entirely. I had very spotty results, possibly due to insufficient training data.

Answer (score 0):

Could there be an example in the training data where something is wrong with the labels? Then when it hits that example the cost become NaN. I'm suggesting this because it seems like it still happens when the learning rate is zero and after just a few batches.

Here is how I would debug:

- Set the batch size to 1
- set the learning rate to 0.0
- when you run a batch have tensorflow output the intermediate values not just the cost
- run until you get a NaN and then check to see what the input was and by examining the intermediate outputs determine at which point there is a NaN

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I will give that a try.  I did thoroughly inspect the training data using the regularly old PyCharm debugger, and everything seems in order with it. I also created a 'dummy' model with much smaller training data randomly generated by NumPy. Still got the NaN error. My strong suspicion is that something devious is wrong with the model itself, but I can't figure it out.